# What exactly is wrong with my implementation of merging two sorted linkedlists in order?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a function in Python3 to merge two sorted linked lists into another list while mantaining the order but it seems to be stuck in an infinite loop.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data  = data 
        self.next  = None #next pointer is None at the moment

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
    def printLinkedList(self):
        currentPointer = self.head
        while (currentPointer!=None):
            print(currentPointer.data)
            currentPointer = currentPointer.next


def mergeTwoSortedLists(linkedList1,linkedList2):
    linkedList1Pointer = linkedList1.head
    linkedList2Pointer = linkedList2.head

    if linkedList1Pointer is None:
        return linkedList2

    if linkedList2Pointer is None:
        return linkedList1

    concatLinkedList = LinkedList()
    concatLinkedListPointer = concatLinkedList.head

    while linkedList1Pointer != None and linkedList2Pointer != None:
        if linkedList1Pointer.data < linkedList2Pointer.data:
            #AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'
            if concatLinkedListPointer is None:
                concatLinkedListPointer = linkedList1Pointer
            else:
                concatLinkedListPointer.next = linkedList1Pointer
            linkedList1Pointer = linkedList1Pointer.next

        else:

            if concatLinkedListPointer is None:
                concatLinkedListPointer =  linkedList2Pointer
            else:
                concatLinkedListPointer.next = linkedList2Pointer
            linkedList2Pointer = linkedList2Pointer.next

        concatLinkedList.printLinkedList()


        concatLinkedListPointer = concatLinkedListPointer.next
    concatLinkedList.printLinkedList()
```

This block of code is there since my list is empty and I am pointing to the first element using the list head itself

```
if concatLinkedListPointer is None:
    concatLinkedListPointer = linkedList1Pointer
```

But the script runs indefinitely but I can't figure out why. I seem to changing the next pointer correctly here.

Comment: Probably better asked here: probably better asked https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @charlesreid1: Code Review is for working code. This code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you merge will work at all, first of all when you do this:

```
concatLinkedList = LinkedList()
concatLinkedListPointer = concatLinkedList.head
```

You get None, if you change it concatLinkedList.head still be point to None. Simple example:

```
concatLinkedList = LinkedList()
concatLinkedListPointer = concatLinkedList.head
concatLinkedListPointer = Node(1)
print(concatLinkedList.head) # None
```

To fix it you should set to your `concatLinkedList.head` new `Node` and update it later in your merge cycle.

Secondly your merge cycle will not work for case when for example first list consist of 1 item and second list consist of 2 items. It will merge item from first list and stop your cycle after it. I assume that first list contains smallest numbers for example.

this is how it can looks like

```
def merge_lists(ll1, ll2):
    head1 = ll1.head
    if head1 is None:
        return head2

    head2 = ll2.head
    if head2 is None:
        return head1

    head = current = Node(None) # empty node we remove it later
    while not (head1 is None or head2 is None):
        if head1.data < head2.data:
            node_to_copy = head1
            head1 = head1.next
        else:
            node_to_copy = head2
            head2 = head2.next
        current.next = node_to_copy
        current = current.next

    current.next = head1 or head2

    result = LinkedList()
    result.head = head.next
    return result
```

Comment: where do you remove the node that was created btw? Is it the part where you return result.head = head.next so that the Node(none) that was created was skipped. Also, back to the original question I tried changing concatLinkedList.head to point to any first element in the if statement [   if concatLinkedListPointer is None: concatLinkedListPointer = linkedList1Pointer]. Just wondering why this wouldn't work

Comment: yes, `head` point to `Node(None)` which was created just for merge operation, so we don't need it and that's why we use next item of this node, which point to correct value and `Node(None)` will be removed by python.

Comment: Understood. Thanks. But is there a way to do it without creating a new dummy node?

Comment: you can create dummy node, but later update it based on `head1` or `head2`, in this case you will have to change merge loop also